# Running commands on file save (asset install automation)

Tags: php, symfony, automation, gruntjs

Is there a way to automate the "php app/console assets:install web" command on each asset save? It's pretty tedious to do it each time I save a CSS file, I thought of a Grunt task but I don't know if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `symlink` your assets:

```
php app/console assets:install --symlink web
```

On Windows Vista and later you need to run as admin command prompt to execute this command...